# How to figure out element's previous index after using the 'sort' method?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I'm writing a simple banking simulation app.

My problem is that I need to figure out previous index of an element. I've got a map:

```
const movsDesc = new Map([[6, 'Bank']]);
```

Here's the original array:

```
const movements: [200, -200, 340, -300, -20, 50, 400, -460];
```

And here's the compare function I'm using:

```
const movsSorted = movements.slice().sort((a, b) => a - b);
```

Then I use `forEach` on the array and in each iteration I create a DOM element for a transaction. It looks like this:

```
movs.forEach(function(mov, i) {
    const type = mov[0] > 0 ? 'deposit' : 'withdrawal';
    const description = currentAccount.movsDesc.get(i) || 'Unknown';
    const html = `
    <div class="movements__row">
      <div class="movements__type movements__type--${type}">${i + 1} ${type}</div>
      <div class='movements__sender'>${type === 'deposit' ? 'from' : 'to'}: ${description}</div>
      <div class="movements__value">${mov[0]}€</div>
    </div>
  `;

  containerMovements.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html);
});
```

It works fine when the array has its original order, so nothing is changed. Each key in the map points to a specified index in the array. Of course when the array is sorted, elements change their positions and therefore they get bad descriptions. That's why I need to keep track of each element's position, so to say.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Is `movements.map((e, i) => [e, i]).sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]);` what you mean? This gives an array of element-index pairs which you can then use as needed.

Comment: @ggorlen Indeed, yes! Thanks for help! I feel ashamed that I haven't thought about that myself.